# Can I debug an MVC 5 application in 2 different sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, visual-studio-debugging

I want to be able to debug two instances of an MVC project as two different users with different sessions. If I use two tabs or even two seperate windows, the session is shared between the two users. Is it possible to seperate sessions while debugging locally?

Comment: Try two different browsers such as Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open two Visual Studio instances and run both projects in two different browsers. Also change port for one project.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll give it a try when I'm free to and accept your answer afterwards if it works.

Comment: Note to others: Debugging the same Visual studio instance with different browsers like Jason suggested worked for me.